# Is anyone else experiencing issues with the word wrap feature in Google BigQuery's SQL Workspace editor?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am using the SQL Workspace editor within Google BigQuery. For months now, I've never had an issue disabling the word wrap feature so that code can extend off screen. However, about two weeks ago, this functionality stopped working.

These are the steps I had previously followed:

1. press Alt+F1 for accessibility options
2. I follow the instruction prompt that says "To configure the editor to be optimized for usage with a Screen Reader press Control+E now", so I press Control+E

Usually after doing this, the word wrap would be disabled and the code would just extend on one long line. However, this is no longer happening for me. Is this an issue for anyone else?

Comment: Yup. Same thing on my end!